# Swift 5 - Using UITableView drag and drop with Realm Results

Tags: swift, drag-and-drop, realm

I'm having a UITableView populated with Realm [Results](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Results.html) that I want to make drag and droppable, using the UITableViewDragDelegate and UITableViewDropDelegate delegates.

I just started learning swift and used a tutorial for implementing the drag and drop functionality. But this works only with an an array of strings. I'm stuck finding a way to have Realm Results transformed into UIDragItems, as the tutorial used strings as item providers.

Thanks for any help!

**My model**

```
class Item: Object {
    @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var position: Int = 0
}
```

**In my view controller**

```
   var items: Results<Item>?
```

**Drag & drop functionality**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        if let item = items?[indexPath.row] {

            //    Attempt to convert the string to a Data object so it can be passed around using drag and drop.
            guard let data = item.data(using: .utf8) else { return [] }

            //    Place that data inside an NSItemProvider, marking it as containing a plain text string so other apps know what to do with it.
            let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(item: data as NSData, typeIdentifier: kUTTypePlainText as String)

            //    Place that item provider inside a UIDragItem so that it can be used for drag and drop by UIKit.
            return [UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)]
        }
    }

    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard sourceIndexPath != destinationIndexPath else { return }
        if let item = items?[sourceIndexPath.row] {
            items.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
            items.insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
        }
    }

    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UITableViewDropProposal {
        var dropProposal = UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .cancel)
        
        // Accept only one drag item.
        guard session.items.count == 1 else { return dropProposal }
        
        dropProposal = UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)

        return dropProposal
    }
    
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
        let destinationIndexPath: IndexPath
        
        if let indexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath {
            destinationIndexPath = indexPath
        } else {
            // Get last index path of table view.
            let section = tableView.numberOfSections - 1
            let row = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section)
            destinationIndexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
        }
        
        coordinator.session.loadObjects(ofClass: NSString.self) { items in
            guard let strings = items as? [String] else { return }
            
            // create an empty array to track rows we've copied
            var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
            
            // loop over all the strings we received
            for (index, item) in strings.enumerated() {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: destinationIndexPath.row + index, section: destinationIndexPath.section)
                
                self.items.insert(item, at: indexPath.row)
                indexPaths.append(indexPath)
            }

            tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You may be asking the wrong question; your tableView *dataSource* is a Results object but the 'stuff' contained in each row is the text from an Item object. So are you asking about dragging the rows in the tableView around within the tableView?

Comment: Hi @Jay - exactly, I want to drag one row within the tableView and update the item's new position in my Realm.

Comment: So all you really need to know is you're dragging row 2 (index 2 in your datasource) and dropping it after row 4 (index 4 in your datasource), right? You really don't care about the actual realm object, just that row 2 is being removed and added after row 4. If you were using a Swift array as a datasource, you would just remove row 2 and insert it after row 4. However, results objects are a bit tricker as they (can be) un ordered so you need a way to keep the ordering consistent. We don't know how your Results object is ordered but you'll need that to make this work.

Comment: Thank you @Jay, you definitely moved me into the right direction. I converted the results objects into an array and got the functionality that I was after for, then reordered the results objects accordingly. This is still not perfect, but I'm looking into Realms List class right now which looks very promising

Comment: Good. However, when you move realm objects to a swift Array, they 'disconnect' from realm and loose their auto-updating capability and become non managed objects. This may not impact your use case but something to be aware of. Lists are really good objects to use as they maintain their ordering at all times.